# DTO is formed with all its null fields

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I am trying to make a post request for ajax with a json that is obtained from another ajax request, but when trying to send the json I have a problem, the controller is getting a dto with all null fields, as if sending a json with all their values null. What am I doing wrong?

I attach the json that I send for my ajax request and the class that of EstateDTO

```
var data=JSON.stringify(item);
ajaxDeleteCeiling(data);

function ajaxDeleteCeiling(data){
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/splan/delete-ceiling',
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                beforeSend: function () {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Loading...',
                        allowOutsideClick: () => !Swal.isLoading(),
                        onBeforeOpen: () => {
                            Swal.showLoading();
                        }
                    });
                },
                success: function
```

```
@PostMapping("delete-ceiling")  
    @ResponseBody
    public EstateDTO deleteCeiling(EstateDTO request) {
        
        String param="";
        
        try {
            param = mapper.writeValueAsString(request);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        
        return restEstate.post(param, new ParameterizedTypeReference<EstateDTO>() {
        }, Consts.CORE_CONTROLLER, Consts.TYPE_CORE);
        
    }
```

```
@Data
public class EstateDTO  extends ResponseDTO {

    private Long idCeiling;
    private String vigence;
    private Long resources;
    private Long idCeiling1;
    private String vigence1;
    private Long resources1;
    private Long idCeiling2;
    private String vigence2;
    private Long resources2;
    private Long idCeiling3;
    private String vigence3;
    private Long resources3;
    private Long idCeiling4;
    private String vigence4;
    private Long resources4;
    private Long idCeiling5;
    private String vigence5;
    private Long resources5;
    private Long total;
    private String codeEntity;
    private Long idPlan;
}
```

```
{
    "codeResponse": null,
    "msgResponse": null,
    "language": null,
    "pag": null,
    "tam": null,
    "list": null,
    "token": null,
    "exit": null,
    "code": 0,
    "objects": null,
    "type": null,
    "Order": null,
    "idCeiling": 72,
    "vigence": "2020",
    "resources": 1212,
    "idCeiling1": 72,
    "vigence1": "2020",
    "resources1": 1212,
    "idCeiling2": 73,
    "vigence2": "2021",
    "resources2": 12,
    "idCeiling3": 74,
    "vigence3": "2022",
    "resources3": 12,
    "idCeiling4": 75,
    "vigence4": "2023",
    "resources4": 1212,
    "idCeiling5": null,
    "vigence5": null,
    "resources5": null,
    "total": 2448,
    "codeEntity": "0001",
    "idPlan": 25
}
```

Comment: You'll need to show us the actual value of `data` and the source code of `EstateDTO`.

Comment: @tgdavies I already added data value and EstateDTO class

Comment: I would try putting a @RequestBody annotation on the request parameter